# Unable to import keras model in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, keras

I am trying to call the following function from Matlab

```
net = importKerasNetworkk('model.h5', 'OutputLayerType', 'classification');
```

and this outputs the following error:

> Layer names in layer array must be different from the names of layers in layer graph.

I'm not able to find any information about how to deal with this error. It seems straight forward to just import the network, why is it insisting that the names be different?

My [keras architecture](https://www.kaggle.com/keegil/keras-u-net-starter-lb-0-277?scriptVersionId=2164855) (from Kaggle) is :

```
inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)

c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (s)
c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p1)
c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p2)
c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c3)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p3)
c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c4)
p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p4)
c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c5)

u6 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u6)
c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c6)

u7 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u7)
c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c7)

u8 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u8)
c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c8)

u9 = Conv2DTranspose(8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u9)
c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c9)

outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
```

Comment: Hi. Have you tried just importing the model (importKerasNetwork('model.h5')) ? Are you sure that the Keras Layer you have in your h5 have a correspondence in Matlab https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/importkerasnetwork.html in Tips.

Comment: Yes, just importing the model doesn't work, it asks for the `OutputLayerType` argument however, I'm not sure if the Keras Layers I have in my h5 have correspondence in Matlab due to use of the Lambda layer. I don't see that on the list of layers in Matlab. But i'm not sure if that's why this error is arising.

Comment: Could you `h5dump --header` the content of your h5 file. Yes the Lambda layer does not seem to have a correspondence. But I agree the message is rather not explicit. And have you tried simply with the Matlab example 'digitsDAGnet.h5' and `h5dump --headers digitsDAGnet.h5` to compare their structure ? (looks close to your layer graph)